# Infer increase/decrease of "real value" of gold from currency values and exchange rates?

Tags: logarithms, percentages

To give a concrete example:

On day $1$, price of Gold $= 947.257$ GBP $= 1326.647$ USD and GBP-USD exchange rate = 1.40034

On day $2$, price of Gold $= 946.276$ GBP $= 1333.332$ USD and GBP-USD exchange rate $= 1.40903$

It can be seen that in GBP the price of Gold has decreased, whilst in USD the price has increased, which is obviously a function of the change in the exchange rate, but also perhaps indicative of a change in the "real value" of Gold.

Given this, I'd like to infer by how much the real, or intrinsic value of gold may have changed ( can be in percentage, logarithm or multiplicative factor ) without necessarily having to know the price levels of this value. Searching on this site I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240805/find-the-real-exchange-rate/240945#240945), the answer to which, intuitively at least, seems to embody the type of approach I should take.

Comment: If you think gold has an intrinsic value, perhaps this is constant and it is merely the fiat currencies (and everything you can buy with those currencies) which are changing price

Comment: I think you want to know the change in value in USD? Or do you really mean intrinsic?